# Why was Martin Harris punished for revealing the Lost 116 pages?

Tags: lds

I am fully aware of the [Messianic Secret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Secret) in Mark, but I don't understand why [Martin Harris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Harris_%28Latter_Day_Saints%29) would feel as though he should be punished for revealing the pages he recorded from Smith's translation of the Golden Plates.  After their loss, it is my understanding that Harris never again served as scribe. Furthermore, according to my tour guide, Smith also claimed responsibility for this loss, stating that "God had to humble him" by "giving into" Smith's desire to let Harris have the pages.

What was so sacred about [these 116 pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_116_pages) that revealing them was so bad?  Was the theology contained therein of particular importance, or was the problem simply that Smith felt he should not have betrayed the command of the Angel?

Along these lines, I'm curious as to the theological significance of what he translated. What was in this material that needed to be protected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Lord had [commanded Joseph Smith to reveal the manuscripts to no one](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1.42?lang=eng#41) who was not involved in the translation. Martin petitioned Joseph three times to show the manuscripts to his (Martin's) wife, and each time Joseph took the issue to the Lord.

The Harris family was wealthy, and Martin was helping pay for the publication of the Book of Mormon. His wife protested and wanted proof of the translation because of his involvement and probably because of the financial burden. Incidentally, she badgered him on the issue and demanded to see the plates -- or *something* convincing.

In response to Joseph's first two pleas, the Lord denied the request, and I believe He even said to trouble Him no more on the matter (See near the end of [D&C 5](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/5?lang=eng)). The third time, the Lord finally permitted it (kind of like the Parable of the Importunate Widow) -- but not without warning of the consequences for disobedience.

Joseph conceded to let Martin take the raw manuscript (but not the actual plates), being the 116 pages that had been translated. Later, Martin returned to Joseph and admitted that he had lost the pages. [Joseph lost his gift to translate and was commanded to repent](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/3.5?lang=eng#4):

> 5 Behold, you have been entrusted with these things, but how strict
>   were your commandments; and remember also the promises which were made
>   to you, if you did not transgress them.
>
> ...
>
> 10 But remember, God is merciful; therefore, repent of that which
>   thou hast done which is contrary to the commandment which I gave you,
>   and thou art still chosen, and art again called to the work;
>
> 11 Except thou do this, thou shalt be delivered up and become as
>   other men, and have no more gift.

The pages consisted of what would be called, probably, the "Book of Lehi" -- writings at the beginning of the plates by Nephi's father, the same Nephi whose writing now starts the Book of Mormon record as we have it today.

In the Book of Mormon, we learn that Nephi [was inspired to re-write at least some of what his father wrote](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/1-ne/19.1-3?lang=eng), so that nothing too important was lost (see vs. 1-3 in linked scriptures for more context) -- emphasized parenthesis my own:

> 3 And after I had made these plates by way of commandment, I, Nephi,
>   received a commandment that the ministry and the prophecies, the more
>   plain and precious parts of them **(Lehi's writings)**, should be written upon these plates;
>   and that the things which were written should be kept for the
>   instruction of my people, who should possess the land, and also for
>   other wise purposes, which purposes are known unto the Lord.

Now, the writings weren't so sacred that nobody could know what they said, but rather, they had to be carefully handled -- and understandably so. Imagine the frenzy if the translation of a record on "gold plates" was public *while it was happening...* especially during a major Christian excitement in the country!

So, the Lord warned Joseph to not re-translate the missing portion because evil men were plotting against them. From [Doctrine and Covenants 10](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/10.1-21?lang=eng#0) (chapter heading):

> Revelation given to Joseph Smith the Prophet, at Harmony,
>   Pennsylvania, in the summer of 1828 (see History of the Church,
>   1:20–23). Herein the Lord informs Joseph of alterations made by wicked
>   men in the 116 manuscript pages from the translation of the book of
>   Lehi, in the Book of Mormon. These manuscript pages had been lost from
>   the possession of Martin Harris, to whom the sheets had been
>   temporarily entrusted. (See the heading to section 3.) The evil design
>   was to await the expected retranslation of the matter covered by the
>   stolen pages and then to discredit the translator by showing
>   discrepancies created by the alterations. That this wicked purpose had
>   been conceived by the evil one and was known to the Lord even while
>   Mormon, the ancient Nephite historian, was making his abridgment of
>   the accumulated plates, is shown in the Book of Mormon (see Words of
>   Mormon 1:3–7).

The whole half of the 10th section is relevant here, but in particular:

> 10 And, behold, Satan hath put it into their hearts to alter the words
>   which you have caused to be written, or which you have translated,
>   which have gone out of your hands.
>
> 11 And behold, I say unto you, that because they have altered the
>   words, they read contrary from that which you translated and caused to
>   be written;
>
> 12 And, on this wise, the devil has sought to lay a cunning plan,
>   that he may destroy this work;
>
> 13 For he hath put into their hearts to do this, that by lying they
>   may say they have caught you in the words which you have pretended to
>   translate.
>
> 14 Verily, I say unto you, that I will not suffer that Satan shall
>   accomplish his evil design in this thing.

## **Summary**

In conclusion: The writings of Lehi were about as sacred as the rest of the Book of Mormon record, but it was vital that the work remain protected against those conspiring against it. And yes, Joseph and Martin both should have obeyed the Lord in this instance -- the first time. But the Lord saw it coming, so He prepared a way for us to still have the important parts of what Lehi wrote and allowed Joseph to repent and continue the translation (with a different scribe -- but Martin Harris still sacrificed in many ways, after losing the manuscript, to support the publication of the Book of Mormon and the Church).

Answer (score 2):

Martin Harris had solemnly promised that he would not show the manuscript except to a few specific persons, and then disregarded that promise and showed it to a few others. After the theft of the manuscript God explained a reason for the secrecy:

> [Doctrine and Covenants 9:35-37](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/9?lang=eng) 
>    35 Marvel not that I said unto you: Here is wisdom, show it not unto
>   the world—for I said, show it not unto the world, that you may be
>   preserved.  36 Behold, I do not say that you shall not show it unto
>   the righteous;  37 But as you cannot always judge the righteous, or as
>   you cannot always tell the wicked from the righteous, therefore I say
>   unto you, hold your peace until I shall see fit to make all things
>   known unto the world concerning the matter.

There is other evidence from the life of Joseph Smith that he had a tendency to be overly trusting of those who treated him well. He was rebuked for letting Martin Harris persuade him to pester God for permission that had been denied.

> [Doctrine and Covenants 3:5-8](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/3?lang=eng) 5 Behold, you have been entrusted
>   with these things, but how strict were your commandments; and remember
>   also the promises which were made to you, if you did not transgress
>   them.  6 And behold, how oft you have transgressed the commandments
>   and the laws of God, and have gone on in the persuasions of men.  7
>   For, behold, you should not have feared man more than God. Although
>   men set at naught the counsels of God, and despise his words—  8 Yet
>   you should have been faithful; and he would have extended his arm and
>   supported you against all the fiery darts of the adversary; and he
>   would have been with you in every time of trouble.

And so was Martin Harris, for failure to keep his promises.

> [Doctrine and Covenants 3:12-13](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/3?lang=eng) 12 And when thou deliveredst up that which God had given thee sight
>   and power to translate, thou deliveredst up that which was sacred into
>   the hands of a wicked man, 13 Who has set at naught the counsels of
>   God, and has broken the most sacred promises which were made before
>   God, and has depended upon his own judgment and boasted in his own
>   wisdom.

The theological import of the missing portion was actually less than what was included in the publication.

> [Doctrine and Covenants 10:44-45](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/10?lang=eng) 44 Behold, they have only got a
>   part, or an abridgment of the account of Nephi. 
>   45 Behold, there are many things engraven upon the plates of Nephi
>   which do throw greater views upon my gospel; therefore, it is wisdom
>   in me that you should translate this first part of the engravings of
>   Nephi, and send forth in this work.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that Martin Harris showed the 116 pages to friends, relatives, and his wife was probably the cause for the loss or theft or destruction of the same.

The suspects in this case would be:

1. Lucy Harris or someone she knew.  She read these pages which were Joseph Smith's first attempt at writing and it showed.  The quality was probably poor and disorganized and later led to a much improved version of what Smith had in mind.  She may have destroyed the pages or one of her friends stole them and destroyed them.
2. Martin Harris or some he knew.  Harris is know to be a liar as evidenced by the two different accounts of the meeting with Professor Anthon.  The copy of the "caractors" shown in the 1945 edition of Fawn Brodie's book indicate "deformed English" and not some Mid-Eastern language.  Anthon would not have stated these to be an authentic translation and Harris knew it.  Harris was testing Smith to see what Smith would do.
3. Joseph Smith himself.  He may have realized that he did a poor job on his "Book of Lehi" and could do better on the next try and he had to have the 116 pages disappear so he hired or got someone else to steal these pages but that someone double-crossed him and never gave the pages back.  Perhaps that "someone" tried to extort him but Smith failed to pay the ransom but that "someone" could not come forth without exposing himself as a thief.

The fact is that the theft was never reported to the constable or sheriff certainly indicts one or more of these suspects.

Comment: This is some good *speculation*, but the site is predicated on sourced answers. In other words, this stuff is fine for an answer like this, but you will need to have at least one credible source that says the same thing.

Comment: Other than that. welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.